# Change label text based on the radio button selection

Tags: php, javascript, text, radio-button

I want to change the label text based on the selection of the radio button. Could you please help me to do it easily. Here is my code.

```
<div class="control-group "> 

            <div class="controls">
              <label class="radio inline">
                   <input type="radio" name="btype[]" id="private" value="private" checked>Private
              </label>
              <label class="radio inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="btype[]" id="business" value="business">Business Advertiser
              </label>
            </div>
    </div>
```

This is the label that i want to change the text

```
<div class="control-group " > 
          <label class="control-label" id="labelName">Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="name" name="name" placeholder="">

              </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group ">
          <label class="control-label" id="labelNum">NIC</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <div class="input-prepend">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="regNum" name="regNum" placeholder="">

              </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

This is my javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function()
          {

             if (($('input[name=btype]:radio:checked').val())=="business") 
             {
               document.getElementById("labelName").innerHTML="Company Name";
               document.getElementById("labelNum").innerHTML="Reg No.";
             }
          }
        );
        </script>
```

Comment: add onclick="document.getElementById('labelid').innerHTML='REPLACEMENT'" to your radio button

Comment: You know what would make this super easy to solve is if you put it in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Since you are using jquery - `$(document).ready(function()`, why are you using pure javascript - `getElementById("labelNum")` instead of jquery - `$("#labelNum")`?

Comment: Since you are new here, accept the answer(tick) which solved your problem. Up-vote(up arrow) the answer(s) which give(s) you information or help(s) you. Down-vote(down arrow) the answer(s) which are fake.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote the code for you in a better way. When you have jQuery use it to the best. Don't get messed up by handling JavaScript. jQuery is there to do it for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function()
          {
             if ($('#business').is(':checked')) 
             {
               $('#labelName').text("Company Name");
               $('#labelNum').text("Reg No.");
             }
          }
        );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

youre mixing jquery in with your js, so heres jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name=btype]:radio:checked').click(function(e){
      if($(e.currentTarget).val()==='business') {
        $("#labelName").text("Company Name");
        $("#labelNum").text("Reg No.");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nCVYL/)

```
onclick="document.getElementById('labelName').innerHTML='NEWLABELNAME'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding a change listener to that inputs and getting the value of the selected one

I have added some HTML5 attributes to avoid getting more DOM 
please look at `data-text`

```
<div class="control-group "> 

            <div class="controls">
              <label class="radio inline">
                   <input type="radio" data-text="private" name="btype[]" id="private" value="private" checked>Private
              </label>
              <label class="radio inline">
                    <input type="radio" data-text="Business Advertiser" name="btype[]" id="business" value="business">Business Advertiser
              </label>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Here is your JS and its jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="btype[]"]').change(function(){
        alert($(this).data('text')); 
    }); 
});
```

You can add more than `data-*` attributes like price or whatever you want and getting the value of it by using `$(this).data('*');`

It's used like this to make your HTML valid and I used it to avoid getting parent text

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gK6bU/1/

I hope this can help :)